# remove milliseconds from Datetime in TZ format

Tags: r, datetime, time, milliseconds

I have a datetime column that contains DateTime in TZ format like:

timestamp = 2021-04-01T04:37:16.528Z

I have to convert/truncate the milliseconds part such that datetime is:

```
as.POSIXct(timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="GMT")

2021-04-01 04:37:16
```

But when I group by DateTime column for aggregations it still uses the timestamp in milliseconds format and the aggregations are not gettig implemented properly.

I want to truncate not just print the DateTime till seconds only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drop the miliseconds part from the string, and then convert:

```
as.POSIXct(gsub("\\.[0-9]+Z", "", timestamp), 
           format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

Comment: Why would you drop them instead of rounding up or down to seconds?

Comment: dropping milliseconds will not change the seconds but rounding up will (e.g 12:12:12.899 will be rounded to 12:12:13). the aggregations will go wrong in this case

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `lubridate`'s `floor_date` function?

```
timestamp <- "2021-04-01T04:37:16.528Z"

as.POSIXct(timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz="GMT") %>% 
  floor_date() %>% 
  format(format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS6")
```

returns `"01.04.2021 04:37:17.000000"`, so the milliseconds are gone.

References: **https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html**